# SelectSingleNode is giving compilation error in dnx core 5.0

Tags: selectsinglenode, dnx50

I am getting this error with SelectSingleNode method:
 DNX Core 5.0 error CS1061: 'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'SelectSingleNode' and no extension method 'SelectSingleNode' accepting a first argument of type 'XmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is it not supported yet? What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

In .Net Core 1.0 and .Net Standard 1.3 SelectSingleNode is an extenstion method

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17349

Add a reference to make it available again:

```
 <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument" Version="4.3.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use XDocument

```
const string xml = "<Misc><E_Mail>email@domain.xyz</E_Mail><Fax_Number>111-222-3333</Fax_Number></Misc>";
const string tagName = "E_Mail";
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement xElement = xDocument.Descendants(tagName).FirstOrDefault();
if (xElement == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"There is no tag with the given name '{tagName}'.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(xElement.Value);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. To solve that, I'm using XDocument and so far so good.

Example:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);
var singleNode = xdoc.Element("someAttr");
var listOfNodes = singleNode.Elements("someAttrInnerText");

foreach (XElement e in listOfNodes)
{
     string someAttr = e.Attribute("code").Value;
     string someAttrInnerText = e.Value;
}
```

Don't forget to include `"System.Xml.XDocument"` inside your **project.json**.