# System.XML equivalent functions in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am creating an application in .NET Core that will handle some XML files.

In .NET 4.6 I have the following code:

```
var document = new XmlDocument(xml);
var node = document.SelectSingleNode("/SOMEPATH");
var value = node.GetValue("//SOMEOTHERPATH");
```

Apparently `SelectSingleNode` and `GetValue` don't exist in System.XML anymore.

What would be the equivalent functions in .NET Core?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089399/selectsinglenode-is-giving-compilation-error-in-dnx-core-5-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17349

> > .Net Core 1.0 and .Net Standard 1.3 have SelectSingleNode as an extension method in the System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument package (the page does not list .Net Standard 1.3, but the package is supported on it), so you will need to add a reference to that package to use it.
> >
> > .Net Core 2.0 and .Net Standard 2.0 change it back to an instance method.

It appears the `Value` of an `XmlNode` can be accessed via [`XmlNode.Value`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Xml.XmlNode.Value).

Comment: Added `"System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument": "4.3.0"` as a dependency and the methods are back. Thanks